# Electricity from Pendulum

Tags: electricity

Can Electricity be generated from a pendulum?. Considering pendulum in its ideal condition i.e. it never stops. If Yes, How? Pendulum can be a simple, complex or any other type. What exactly I mean to ask is Can the oscillatory motion of the pendulum be converted into other kind of motions and then convert that motion into generating electricity, may be by connecting a dynamo?

Comment: As soon as you extract energy the pendulum would slow and then stop, unless it was powered eg by clockwork

Comment: Energy is always conserved. So, even when the pendulum-electricity apparatus is kept in vacuum, it will eventually stop working when all the $\text{Mechanical Energy}$($PE$ and $KE$) of the bob gets converted into $\text{electrical energy}$

Comment: If someone wants to answer the question, then please don't comment. And please upvote the question if you think that this shows any research effort; clear and useful, because it is taking away my reputation.

Comment: I think you got downvoted because, in the way it is written, you seem to assume that the pendulum will create electricity without stopping, which in turns means that energy is created, which goes against the classical laws of physics. The question also doesn't show any kind of research effort (such as the basic laws of physics).

Comment: What I mean to ask is can the pendulum motion be converted to some other motion and from that electricity can be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pendulum motion can be converted to energy any number of ways. For example, if the pendulum bob is a magnet simply placing a coil of wire near it as it swings will induce a current which can be siphoned off and used.

Comment: I need the most effective way of generating Electricity

Comment: In which case, the coil and magnet are the best bet. However, you would need to optimize the materials and mechanical configuration. The magnet should fully penetrate the coil on each swing, and it should be a high field strength Neodymium. The coil should contain as many turns of wire as practical. It should then feed into a bridge full wave rectifier which then charges a capacitor. If you get it right, almost all the energy of the first swing will be sucked out of the system and put into the capacitor. The pendulum will then come to a rapid halt.

Comment: So basically I would be getting Alternating Current, I have to use **Rectifiers** to convert it into Direct Current?